# dns error in cpanel while i try to activate ssl

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting

i get this error while i try to activate ssl . before i change all the file in public html the ssl worked fine . what can i do to solve this problem.
"                                                                                     DNS DCV: No local authority: “mail.sitename.com.tr”; HTTP DCV: The system queried for a temporary file at “https://webmail.turkticaret.net/.well-known/pki-validation/C25C8B17A815CDA88D7BD866DA9046.txt”, which was redirected from “http://mail.sitename.com.tr/.well-known/pki-validation/C25C8B17A815CDA88D7BD866DA9046.txt”. The web server responded with the following error: 404 (Not Found). A DNS (Domain Name System) or web server misconfiguration may exist. The domain “mail.sitename.com.tr” resolved to an IP address “11.222.33.444” that does not exist on this server.                                                       "

11.222.33.444 is random.

i get this error while i try to activate ssl . before i change all the file in public html the ssl worked fine . what can i do to solve this problem.